# How to get value of the ignore_malformed parameter in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, curl, mapping

To update the `ignore_malformed` parameter of Elasticsearch using curl we have :

```
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/index?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"settings": {"index.mapping.ignore_malformed": true}'
```

Is there a way to get the value of this parameter using curl ?

I have already tried `_settings` & `_mappping` endpoints, but didn't get the wanted result which should be something like:

```
{...
{"ignore_malformed": true}
...}
```

Comment: Just doing a `GET my_index/_settings` call should give you back `"settings": { index": { "mapping": { "ignore_malformed": "true" } ... }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Elastic documentation on [ignore_malformed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-malformed.html#ignore-malformed-setting). You can use the `_settings` call to get what you want.

> The `index.mapping.ignore_malformed` setting can be set on the index
>   level to allow to ignore malformed content globally across all mapping
>   types.
>
> ```
> PUT my_index
> {
>   "settings": {
>     "index.mapping.ignore_malformed": true 
>   },
>   "mappings": {
>     "_doc": {
>       "properties": {
>         "number_one": { 
>           "type": "byte"
>         },
>         "number_two": {
>           "type": "integer",
>           "ignore_malformed": false 
>         }
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Then to retrieve the setting just do a `GET my_index/_settings` which will return:

```
{
  "my_index": {
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "mapping": {
          "ignore_malformed": "true"
        },
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "provided_name": "my_index",
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, just one detail, if the parameter `ignore_malformed` is not called during the creation of the index, it wont show up on the `GET index/_settings` output, hence the reason why I didn't get it before.